Custom join in a @ManyToMany or @OneToMany mapping without join table
I'm trying to define a custom join condition between the two following entities.
class Period {
  private long id;
  private String category;
  private Date start;
  private Date end;
  
  @ManyToMany // Or @OneToMany
  private Collection<Event> events
}

class Event {
  private long id;
  private String category;
  private Date date;
}

I want to retrieve in Period all the Event that have the same category and a date within start and end (In may case, the relationship is effectively a @OneToMany as no two periods with the same category overlap, but any working solution with @OneToMany or @ManyToMany would satisfy me). In sql, the join is simple:
select *
  from period p
  join event e on p.category = e.category
    and e.date >= p.start
    and e.date <= p.end;

I've tried multiple things, including @Formulas and @JoinColumnsOrFormulas and weird @JoinColumns in @ManyToMany trying to use the event table as a join column, but nothing works or I didn't find the good syntax.
With @JoinColumnsOrFormulas, I can retrieve one Event, but I want a collection of Event, not a single one.
If the date condition is impossible, even retrieving all the Event with the same category would be acceptable in my case, but even that seems impossible.
Note on similar question
I'm aware of this question, which concerns a @ManyToOne mapping retrieving a single child entity.

First, I won't overuse mapping for this kind of use case. Maybe object loading by Criteria API.
Second, look into https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter-join-table

Hi elcye. A quick note: thanks and other conversational items tend to be removed here as part of a longstanding consensus about technical writing. See this canonical on the Meta site (there are several others besides).

Use
@JoinColumn(name = "category", referencedColumnName = "category")
@OneToMany
private Collection<Event> events;

Unfortunately no additional filtering available.
@JoinFormula doesn't work with @OneToMany. There is open feature request here.

The @JoinColumn version is standard JPA (whereas @JoinFormula is not), but it supports only equijoins, not more general join conditions such as the OP says they would prefer.

Apparently JoinFormula doesn't work with collections.

@JoinFormula is claimed to work with collection-valued relationships.  Here, for example, or especially here.  That seems to be the intent, too.  Apparently, however, that combination is buggy in at least some versions of Hibernate.

Actually, sorry, that middle link documents use with a many-to-one, but does not involve a collection

I found a test that checks that this combination is not permitted (org.hibernate.orm.test.annotations.formula.JoinColumnOrFormulaTest)

No, that's a different feature being tested (@JoinColumnOrFormula, which is not the same thing as @JoinColumn + @JoinFormula). Also it's a "known not to work" test associated with a bug report, not a "fails by design" test.  Hibernate clearly does have issues in this general area, but it's useful and appropriate to distinguish between "you're not supposed to do that" and "Hibernate is buggy".

I don't have any insight about hibernate plans and policies. I just judge by code I found in their repository :) so sometime I misinterpret their intentions. The fact is it doesn't work now :(
